# Data-Binding in Python?

Tags: python, data-binding

I readily admit that I might be referring to this by the wrong name or wanting something that I shouldn't need. I'm just hung up on wanting this to be a thing: linking together object attributes so that if I change one, that I'll change the other. Always. Until I do something to disconnect them on purpose.

So let's go straight into an example:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ["Thing1"]

a = Example()
b = Example()
c = Example()

a.name = b.name

b.name.append("Thing2")
b.name.remove("Thing1")
```

So now `a.name` and `b.name` are connected so that they both are names for the same mutable, which now reads `["Thing2"]`. And further, `c.name` is a name of a different value `["Thing1"]`.

I've now accomplished what I want to do: `a.name` and `b.name` are linked. But this is tremendously kludgy.

I could make a custom list Class and create some methods to switch out the thing in the list and return an immutable when called, so that it looks more like a normal immutable. But all that seems like a hack.

Any thoughts on making this cleaner? Or am I simply wanting a bad thing?

Comment: You can wrap `name` in an object with reference semantics; ex. `a.name = ["foo"]; b.name = ["bar"]; a.name = b.name; a.name[0] = "baz"; print(b.name[0]) # baz`

Comment: *However, since x has a value change, y is now 4.* -- incorrect.  `y` still references 8 -- try it.

Comment: @jedwards, I stand corrected, and will change my example as appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, when you do re-definition

```
x = 8
y = x
x = 4   # <-- Re-definition of x
```

`x` and `y` will no longer reference the same thing (try `print id(x) == id(y)`).

Consider how re-definition works:

```
x = 8
y = x
x = 4
print y     # Still 8

x = "foo"
y = x
x = "bar"
print y     # Still 'foo'

x = [1,2,3]
y = x
x = [4,5,6]
print y     # Still [1,2,3]
```

What you *can* do, with **mutable types** is to change the object "in place".

For example,

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x
```

Now, both `x` and `y` reference the same list (`print id(x) == id(y)`).

Now we can *replace* the elements, by using only `x`:

```
x[:] = [4,5,6]
```

Here, we're not re-defining `x`, we're just modifying the values in the list.

In this case, the changes *will* be reflected in `y`:

```
print y     # Now [4,5,6]
```

Note:

```
print id(x) == id(y)  # True
```

If you want the ability to modify in-place an immutable type, you can "fake" it by wrapping it in a list:

```
x = ["Foo"]  # Strings are immutable
y = x
x[0] = "Bar"
print y               # ['Bar']
print id(x) == id(y)  # True
```

There will be *a million* questions on here about mutable / immutable types -- you should review them.

---

**Edit** We *could* accomplish what you want with your `bind` line with a combination of mutable types and [properties](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

First, we create a "fake" mutable string class:

```
class FakeMutableString(object):
    def __init__(self, s=""):
        self.s = [s]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.s[0]

    def get(self):
        return self.s[0]

    def set(self, new):
        self.s[0] = new
```

And to see how it works

```
x = FakeMutableString("Foo")
y = x
x.set("Bar")
print y             # Prints 'Bar' -- Change in x is reflected in y
```

Note that *we don't* re-assign to `x` -- instead we use the `x.set()` method.  If we re-assigned to `x`, we'd ruin everything (as we talked about above).

Then, we can modify your `Example` class to the following:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = FakeMutableString()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name.get()

    @name.setter
    def name(self, new):
        self._name.set(new)
```

`Example` instances have an attribute `_name` attribute that references a `FakeMutableString` object.

But with properties, we can pretend we're providing direct attribute access, while hiding the actual implementation.

So we can do something like:

```
# Create Example instances
a = Example()
b = Example()
c = Example()

# Set their name attributes 
#   ( this actually calls <Example>._name.set() )
a.name = "ThingA"
b.name = "ThingB"
c.name = "ThingC"

# Access and print their name attributes
#   ( this actually calls <Example>._name.get() )
print a.name, b.name, c.name    # ThingA ThingB ThingC

# We can't bind like you suggested, but we can change what b._name points to
#   So here, we change b._name to point to the FakeMutableString a._name points to
b._name = a._name

# Now when we print the names, we see something different
print a.name, b.name, c.name    # ThingA ThingA ThingC

# And we can make a change in a, and have it reflected in b
a.name = "CommonName"
print a.name, b.name, c.name    # CommonName CommonName ThingC

# And vice-versa
b.name = "StillCommon"
print a.name, b.name, c.name    # StillCommon StillCommon ThingC
```

Comment: OK, so my bad on not using a mutable type, such as the list in my example, but I don't think you really addressed my core question, but I'll key off your example: how do I make it so that if x = [1,2,3] and y = x, that I can mutate y to change x?

Comment: If you *mutate* y, it will change x -- for example `y.append(4)`.  If you *re-assign / re-define* y, they will then reference different things.  Does this help?

Comment: Ah! Yes! And even though I've read all sorts of stuff about mutable vs. immutable types, I've for some reason still held onto the idea that y has a reference to x, not that y and x both *share* the same mutable value. I guess I need to massively re-frame my question.

Comment: so thanks by the way for clearing up my misunderstanding. I've been working in this language now for 6 months, and somehow I missed this vital distinction.

Comment: @raiderrobert I updated my answer to illustrate one way you could accomplish you "binding" goal -- it may be too much, but the properties language feature are worth looking into in general